# jQuery validate and groups - how to avoid errorPlacement usage?

Tags: jquery-validate

Current [example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) of `groups` usage says that `errorPlacement` should be defined, where names of fields are hard coded:

```javascript
$("#myform").validate({
  groups: {
    username: "fname lname"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.attr("name") == "fname" 
                 || element.attr("name") == "lname" )
       error.insertAfter("#lastname");
     else
       error.insertAfter(element);
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

Is there any way to get rid of this `errorPlacement` with field names? The error message should be always places after last element in the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're going to have to use `errorPlacement`, but you can pull out a few tricks to get the error in a consistent place among groups every time:

```javascript
$("#test-form").validate({
    groups: { 
      username: "fname lname",
      range: "min max"
    },
    errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
      var elementName = $element.attr("name"),
          lastInGroup = $.map(this.groups, function(fields, name) {
            var fieldsArr;
            if (fields.indexOf(elementName) >= 0) {
              fieldsArr = fields.split(" ");
              return fieldsArr[fieldsArr.length - 1];
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })[0];

      if (lastInGroup) {      
          $error.insertAfter($("input[name='" + lastInGroup + "']"));
      } else {
          $error.insertAfter($element);
      }
    }
});
```

Basically, access the `groups` object that you've defined and find the last field in every group. Attach the error after that field.

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/acenic/

Comment: @LA_: No problem! Thanks for the interesting problem `:)`

Comment: I've just found another problem - code above works well with elements, which are part of group. But in case this is single element, then error msg is just not displayed. Is there any way to fix it? See example - http://jsbin.com/emipos/2 (last field is mandatory, but error msg is not shown).

Comment: @LA_: Sorry about that--All you should have to do is check if `lastInGroup` exists. Updated the answer.

Comment: I've found one more problem with `groups` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691250/jquery-validate-and-groups-doesnt-work-properly-when-second-field-value-is-co. Andrew, probably you will be able help me )).

Comment: Hmm, another bug - if use field `passport-issued-by` and group of two fields `passport-issued-by-code-1` and `passport-issued-by-code-1`, then this code treats first field (`passport-issued-by`) as part of the group. Here is what I have in `groups`: `"passport-issued-by-code": "passport-issued-by-code-1 passport-issued-by-code-2"`. Seems the problem is with `indexOf` line.