# jQuery validate and groups - doesn't work properly when second field value is correct?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have some fields, which are part of group - [demo](http://jsbin.com/ukecog/edit#preview).
When user inputs wrong data in first field (*Digits (1 to 10)* in my demo), then error message is shown. But when user inputs correct data in the second field (*Digits (11 to 20)*), this message disappears, when one field in the group still contains incorrect data. Moreover, error class is removed (this is not visible in the demo).

How can I correct that?

Comment: @r0m4n, right, but it doesn't affect functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known fact this problem with groups on jQuery validation.

My solution is very simple.

First of all, you need to add the same class to all of your inputs in the group:

```
<input id="firstInGroup" class="groupBug">
<input id="secondInGroup" class="groupBug">
<input id="thirdInGroup" class="groupBug">
```

Then, you create a trigger to that class

```
    $('.groupBug').change(function(){
    if($(this).siblings().valid()){
        //all items of the group are valid, do nothing or manually add valid class
    }else{
        //add the error class to the parent div, or whatever you want for the error
    }
```

It worked for me with a couple of selects.

Answer (score 0):

The validation you wanna don't need to be a grouped one...

What is happening with your code is that when you group a validation only one error element is created and since the validation occurrs, by default, onfocusout or onkeyup, each element that has a rule different from 'required' is tested on these events.

So, when the validation tests the first field and find an error, it shows the message, but when the validation tests the second one and this is correct, it remove the error message.

What you need is remove the group from these fields since they don't be a group validation, or cancel the validation from starting on focusout or keyup events

Comment: They are grouped since I want to have only one error message for them. And I want to have validation on `focusout`. Probably, I should create custom validation rule, where I should check values in all grouped fields? But how can it be created flexible (i.e. will work with all groups I have)?

Comment: what you want is a bit confusing... what happens if I insert a wrong data in first field and then insert wrong data in the second? Both of them will be wrongs but only one (probably the second) will be alerted as wrong...